# React Native Security Issues in Android Signed apk. 2 Issues: 1) app creates temp file & 2) TCP Socket used)

Tags: react-native, tcp

Environment
OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.4
Node: 10.1.0
Yarn: Not Found
npm: 5.6.0
Watchman: 4.9.0
Xcode: Xcode 9.3.1 Build version 9E501
Android Studio: 3.2 AI-181.5540.7.32.5014246

```
Packages: (wanted => installed)
react: 16.3.1 => 16.3.1
react-native: 0.55.4 => 0.55.4
```

Description
We are using the tool Codified Security to find out the security issues in the signed apk and we are getting the following security issues:

1. App creates a temp file :
   You need to fix this because:

Sensitive data might be written into a temp file.
You can fix this by changing this in your code.

Avoid creating temp files.
Common Weakness Enumeration

CWE-295 — The software does not validate, or incorrectly validates, a
certificate.

Problem has been found in:

```
    com/facebook/cache/disk/DefaultDiskStorage.java
    try { paramString = new InserterImpl(paramString, paramObject.createTempFile(localFile)); return paramString; localStringBuilder.append(resourceId); localStringBuilder.append("."); return File.createTempFile(localStringBuilder.toString(), ".tmp", paramFile); }

    com/facebook/react/modules/camera/ImageEditingManager.java

    paramContext = localFile; } return File.createTempFile("ReactNative_cropped_image_", getFileExtensionForType(paramString), paramContext); } if ((localObject != null) && (! ((String)localObject).isEmpty())) { File localFile = ImageEditingManager.createTempFile(mContext, (String)localObject); ImageEditingManager.writeCompressedBitmapToFile(paramVarArgs, (String)localObject, localFile); 
    com/google/android/gms/common/data/BitmapTeleporter.java
    try { localFile = File.createTempFile("teleporter", ".tmp", zali); }
```

2. TCP socket usage detected

   You need to fix this because:
   TCP sockets need to be encrypted otherwise it may be vulnerable to the following attack mechanisms: DoS attacks, replay attacks, man in the middle (MITM) attacks, eavesdropping and subsequent impersonation. It's highly recommended to use TLS or other methods to secure your connection.
   Common Weakness Enumeration
   CWE-941 — The software creates a communication channel to initiate an outgoing request to an actor, but it does not correctly specify the intended destination for that actor.
   More information can be seen on the CWE website

   ## PCI compliance.

   This app may be in breach of PCI-DSS 2.2.3, 2.3 and 4.1.
   SSL and early TLS (versions lower than 1.2) are not considered strong cryptography.
   HIPAA compliance.
   Transmission Security
   This app may be in breach of HIPAA encryption requirements.
   SSL and early TLS (versions lower than 1.2) are not considered strong cryptography.
   GDPR compliance.
   This app may be in breach of GDPR encryption requirements.
   SSL and early TLS (versions lower than 1.2) are not considered strong cryptography.
   OWASP compliance.
   OWASP M3: Insufficient Transport Layer Protection
   This app may be in breach of OWASP encryption requirements.

   SSL and early TLS (versions lower than 1.2) are not considered strong cryptography.
   Problem has been found in:

   ```
   okio/Okio.java

   import java.io.InterruptedIOException; import java.io.OutputStream;
   import java.net.Socket;
     import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
   okhttp3/Connection.java

   package okhttp3; import java.net.Socket;

   okhttp3/ConnectionPool.java

   import java.lang.ref.Reference; import java.net.Socket; 
   import java.util.ArrayDeque;
   okhttp3/OkHttpClient.java

   import java.net.Proxy;
   import java.net.ProxySelector; import java.net.Socket;
   import java.net.UnknownHostException

   okhttp3/interal/Internal.java

   import java.net.MalformedURLException; 
   import java.net.Socket;
   import java.net.UnknownHostException;
   okhttp3/internal/Util.java

   import java.lang.reflect.Array; import java.net.IDN;
   import java.net.ServerSocket;
   import java.net.Socket;
   import java.net.IDN;
   import java.net.ServerSocket;
   import java.net.Socket;
   import java.nio.charset.Charset;

   okhttp3/internal/connection/RealConnection.java

   import java.net.Proxy; import java.net.Proxy.Type; 
   import java.net.Socket;
   import java.net.SocketException

   Object localObject2 = route.address();
    if ((((Proxy)localObject1).type() != Proxy.Type.DIRECT)
     && (((Proxy)localObject1).type() != Proxy.Type.HTTP)) {
   localObject1 = new Socket((Proxy)localObject1);
   } else {
   okhttp3/internal/connection/StreamAllocation.java

   import java.lang.ref.Reference; 
   import java.lang.ref.WeakReference; 
   import java.net.Socket;
   import java.util.List;

   okhttp3/internal/http2/Http2Connection.java

   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.net.InetSocketAddress; 
   import java.net.Socket;
   import java.util.Collection;
   okhttp3/internal/platform/AndroidPlatform.java

   import java.lang.reflect.Method; 
   import java.net.InetSocketAddress; 
   import java.net.Socket;
   import java.security.cert.Certificate;
   okhttp3/internal/platform/Platform.java

   import java.lang.reflect.Field; 
   import java.net.InetSocketAddress; 
   import java.net.Socket;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   okhttp3/internal/ws/RealWebSocket.java

   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.net.ProtocolException; 
   import java.net.Socket;
   import java.util.ArrayDeque;
   com/facebook/react/modules/network/TLSSocketFactory.java

   import java.io.IOException; 
   import java.net.InetAddress; 
   import java.net.Socket; 
   import java.net.UnknownHostException;
   ```

   Please suggest how we can resolve these issues.

   Thanks

Comment: Change your app to not do those things. Or don't use this app in an area which requires you to be PCI compliant and/or GDPR compliant. Or get a lawyer.